# Can i convert java to typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

i wanted to use google text recognizer API in my ionic2 (Typescript & Angular2) project.I was wondering if i am able to use them? details about the API can be found under this link https://developers.google.com/vision/text-overview

The above API and its documentations seems to be in java (Android development) So may i know if i can actually use this API for ionic2 instead?.Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Probably not. That's the difference between writing native apps vs html apps.

Comment: Is this not one of the reason using something like nativescript is better? Because it compiles to native? So in other words I think that if you wrote this in nativescript the typescript would compile to java. Which means that there is indeed a way to compile typescript to java. But not without  a bunch of work. Or just use nativescript instead of ionic. You can use ng-2 in nativescript. It is very close to the same thing. Ionic uses webview nativescript compiles to native. I know this is probably not what you want to hear. But if you have the choice I think you should consider it.

Comment: @wuno do you mean using typescript codes in Java?

Comment: I mean if you write your app in nativescript it compiles to native. I am not sure if that will work or not. I am just letting you know. It actually compiles to the native language. Ionic does not.

Comment: @wuno i see, thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can convert java code to typescript. But you should use NativeScript Framework.

**Example Code:**

**Java: (Native Android):**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:com.example.mypackage"));
startActivity(intent);
```

**Typescript:**

```
import * as app from "tns-core-modules/application";
const androidApp = app.android;

 var intent : any = new android.content.Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
                intent.setData(android.net.Uri.parse("package:" +YOUR_APP_URL));
                 androidApp.foregroundActivity.startActivity(intent);
```